# How to plot start date to end data using pandas and plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to plot a graph using pandas and plotly from start to end. I am taking dates between '2022-12-18' and '2022-12-20', but it is not plotting for the end date. It is only plotting for 18 and 19, not for 20.
Please give some suggestions on how I can resolve this problem,
Here also, I am sharing my sample code.

```
mask = (df['received_at'] >= start_date) & (df['received_at'] <= end_date)
df2 = df.loc[mask]
df2['Kwh1'] = df['object'].str.get('Kwh1')
fig = px.scatter(df2, x = df2['received_at'],y = df2['Kwh1'])
fig.show()
```

Comment: can you add a sample of your data to the question? you can copy and paste the output from `df.head(10).to_dict()` into your question – this will help us reproduce your error, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to this question. We can add time with the date, so this will work for both the start and end dates.
like start_date ='2022-12-18 00:00:00' and end_date = '20222-12-21 23:59:59'.
This will work for both the start date and the end date.

Comment: You can improve your answer's long-term value and make it more likely to attract upvotes by including the specific solution you implemented in code, as well as your final result.